# Approve pull request changes tasks to done automatically

Tags: git, azure-devops, pull-request

I'm using azure devops project with git.
When I approve a pull request, it changes the task that is associated with pull request to done automatically.

In my project, our QA team test the task after pull request, so i need a way to approve pull request without change any status of a task or bug.

I don't found a configuration to disable it.
Is there any configuration to disable this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you approve the pull request, there is a [check box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRqOg.jpg) to complete any linked work items. If you uncheck it, the linked work items won't change to status done.

Comment: Works. I don't know how can I didn't see this option before. Thanks!